# Android - How to share the app on Facebook immediately after clicking on a button

Tags: android, facebook, share

I want to share one image in my app on Facebook with just one click. Users cannot see the post so they don't need to do any things else after clicking on a button.

Note: **Don't** use Facebook SDK

Thanks for any help!

Comment: well you can't... Facebook doesn't allow apps to send data directly unless your app is integrated with their account, As every app which is capable of sharing data on Facebook needs authentication from them. Well, should you be able to send images directly without Facebook sdk integration let me know..

Comment: Hi @PankajNimgade ,i integrated FB sdk,now i want to enable one click share i.e i dont want that sharedialog to appear.Can you help me out?